# Rails Model Attribute Selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a new model and I would like to add an attribute that is a selector. How do you do this? What is the class?

I have the standard :integer, :datetime, etc.

I would like a type:

Selector would have multiple choices ['run', 'ride', 'drive', 'fly']

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no class in ruby for this, the closest you can get is with:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  MyOptions = ['run', 'ride', 'drive', 'fly']

  validates :my_attributes, inclusion: {in: MyOptions}
end
```

If you want to go step further, you can override setters to raise an exception if value is not in allowed values:

```
class InvalidValue < StandardError
end

def my_attribute=(value)
  raise InvalidValue.new unless MyOptions.include?(value)
  super
end
```

Comment: Thanks, How would I generate this? rails generate migration add_type_to_events type:???

Comment: Beware of attributes named `type`: you will need to add `self.inheritance_column = nil` to your class as well. To the question above you generate it as usual string column - it will be stored internally as a string. `rails g migration add_<your_column>_to_<your_table> <your_column>:string`

Answer (score 0):

There are [loads](https://github.com/electronick/enum_column) of [different](https://github.com/jeffp/enumerated_attribute) [solutions](https://github.com/ikspres/enum_fu) [available](https://github.com/adzap/active_enum) for implementing an enumerable attribute within a Rails model.

These tend to approach the issue from the same perspective as BroiSatse's answer, but provide more comprehensive validations, helper methods, etc.

Take a look through these links and see which best fits your needs.

https://github.com/electronick/enum_column

https://github.com/jeffp/enumerated_attribute

https://github.com/ikspres/enum_fu

https://github.com/adzap/active_enum

Answer (score 0):

Camelcase is the convention for class names. I would go with a constant:

```
  MY_OPTIONS = %w(run ride drive fly).freeze
```